# Angular code not running on server after deployment

Tags: angular, tomcat

I am using angular 8

when I am building my project on local by using "ng build" or "ng build --prod true" its working fine.

```
   local URL is http://localhost:4200/apw/
```

But when I am deploying my code on server (server is using maven angular plugin to build and deploy code),its not working (like when I am running build by using tomcat server)
and running code on https://ciigate.apexxfintech.com/apw/

Its showing error in console ,not able to find  main files like main.js , pollyfills.ts, runtime.js etc.
So showing nothing on https://ciigate.apexxfintech.com/apw/

[image]

this is my index.html

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Apexx Portal</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <!-- material icons import-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know if you need any other info regarding same

Comment: are you running ```ng build --prod``` before deploying? if not you will have to do so as it will create your /dist folder with the necessary files

Comment: Frontend code is not deployed properly on server.

Comment: @AayushGupta yes

Comment: But this is not running even if I am running tomcat server locally like this http://localhost:8081/apw/ (here 8081 is tomcat port). Though working fine on http://localhost:4200/apw/

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you are getting is because you have not defined the right paths in your angular.json file like this:

**SAMPLE ANGULAR.JSON SNIPPET**

```
"options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",   //Define your main,runtime,polyfills routes here
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
              "src/assets/scss/paper-dashboard.scss",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
            ]
          },
```

After updating the file do a build --prod again and then deploy it.

Comment: thanks for your reply but these all paths are defined in my angular.json

Comment: "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/apexx-portal-ui",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [ 
            ]
          },

Comment: oh is it! then this is seriously some issue, wait i will look onto it